# Is KKT condition always sufficient for optimality?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Should I make assumptions about the function such that the function should be differentiable or convex. I am really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need differentiability to write down the KKT conditions, a constraint qualification to get the necessity and convexity to get sufficiency.

Comment: But note that if the problem is convex, then there is a version of the KKT conditions that doesn't require differentiability.

Comment: Do you refer to a condition including the subdifferential of the objective and the normal cone to the feasible set? I think that I would not call these conditions 'KKT conditions'.

Comment: I was thinking of the four conditions on slide 4-27 of Vandenberghe's 236c notes:  http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/subgradients.pdf

Comment: Oh. I was not aware that somebody actually call this KKT conditions. Karush and also Kuhn and Tucker only addressed the differentiable case.